# Database Connection and Populating ListBox in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to show the results in a windows app form using visual basic but i keep getting this Exception errors:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@Skill nvarchar(4000))SELECT a.Skill FROM Spells a INNER JOIN C' expects the parameter '@Skill', which was not supplied.'

I don't know what to do, thank you for your time and consideration

Here is my whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace rpg_game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

    connectionString=ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["rpg_game.Properties.Settings
    .charactersConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            Populatebox();
        }

        private void Populatebox()
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM unit_tb", connection))
            {
                DataTable unit_table = new DataTable();

                adapter.Fill(unit_table);

                Name_list.DisplayMember = "Name";
                Name_list.ValueMember = "Id";
                Name_list.DataSource = unit_table;
            }
        }

        private void Populatebox2()
        {
            string query = "SELECT a.Skill FROM Spells a INNER JOIN Character_Skills b ON a.Id = b.spell_id WHERE b.unit_id  = @Skill";

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Skill", Class_list.SelectedValue);
                DataTable unit_table2 = new DataTable();

                adapter.Fill(unit_table2);

                Class_list.DisplayMember = "Skill";
                Class_list.ValueMember = "Id";
                Class_list.DataSource = unit_table2;
            }
        }

        private void Class_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Populatebox2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The values returned by `Class_list.SelectedValue` must not be null and have a definite value, eg. 1, 2, 3, A, B, C

Comment: @GrantWinney The verbatim symbol is not a verbatim symbol when it is inside a string. SQL Server is looking for "@Skill" as parameter name.

Comment: @GrantWinney You are correct. I even checked it with stored procedures. However, I still say @"my string with \ " is different from "@myString"

Answer (score 0):

> Expects the parameter '@Skill', which was not supplied.'

The message its clear, the query its ok but the value of the parameter @Skill is `null` so check `Class_list.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

I finally Go it guys! thanks for your help!

I was really stupid now that I realized it, I just need to change this part of the code:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Skill", 
Class_list.SelectedValue);
```

into:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Skill", 
Name_list.SelectedValue);
```

Since what I want to do is to get the value of the name of the character of my database which is "JAY" with the value of 1, which will then in turn be copied to the @skill as one resulting in this result:

[What result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRQWK.png)

Where every time I clicked on a new name their skills will appear as per described in my database

Once again guys thanks for the heads up